# What is nullification with respect to an Eilenberg-MacLane space?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

By nullification with respect to $K(A,n)$, I mean the Bousfield localization $L_{A,n}$ where a spectrum $E$ is $L_{A,n}$-local if and only if $\tilde E^\ast(K(A,n)) = 0$.

**Question:** Is there a good description of which spectra are $L_{A,n}$-local? Is there a good description of the localization functor $L_{A,n}$?

Notes:

- I'd be happy to understand the case $A = \mathbb Z/p$ when $E$ is also $p$-local.
- For example, $K(n)$-local spectra are $L_{\mathbb Z/p,m}$-local for $m \geq n+1$.
- If $E$ is $L_{A,n}$-local, then $E$ is also $L_{A,n+1}$-local. This follows from the Zabrodsky lemma. As a consequence, $HA$ is $L_{A,n}$-acyclic for all $n$.
- It's a fact (due to Bousfield I think) that $K(\mathbb Z/p, n)$ is always either $E$-local or $E$-acyclic (as a space -- note that $E$-acyclicicity the same whether we consider $K(\mathbb Z/p,n)$ as a space or suspension spectruem, but $E$-locality may be different I think).
- And I believe any nontrivial homological localization of $p$-local spectra [**EDIT:** assuming it kills some suspension spectrum -- e.g. not the harmonic localization!] must kill some $K(\mathbb Z/p,n)$.  <strike>So I'm asking about the "minimally nontrivial" localizations of $p$-local spectra.</strike> This follows from the theorem of Bousfield that if a *space* $X$ is $E$-acyclic, then $K(\pi_n(X), n)$ is $E$-acyclic, and then you can show that if some $K(A,n)$ is $E$-acyclic, so is $K(\mathbb Z/p, n)$ for some $p$.
- One form of the Sullivan conjecture ([proved by Miller](https://www.doi.org/10.2307/2007071) says that in the unstable case, every finite-dimensional complex is $L_{A,n}^{unst}$-local for every finite $A$ and $n \geq 1$.
- A related [theorem of Lee](https://www.doi.org/10.2307/2374709) says that in the stable case, every finite spectrum is $L_{A,n}$-local for every finite $A$ and $n \geq 2$. Unlike the unstable case, I don't think this extends to finite-dimensional spectra -- e.g. I think it already fails for any infinite wedge of equidimensional spheres. Certainly it fails even for the finite case at $n=1$ by the Segal conjecture (proved by Carlsson).
- Nick Kuhn points out in his answer below that in the unstable case, Neisendorfer showed the following:

  > Let $X$ be the $p$-completion of a simply-connected finite space with $\pi_2(X)$ finite. Then for all $m \in \mathbb N$, we have $L_{\mathbb Z/p, 1}^{unst} \tau_{\geq m} X = X$.

  I believe this extends to say that if $X$ is the $p$-completion of an $n$-connected finite space with $\pi_{n+1}(X)$ finite, then for all $m$ we have $L_{\mathbb Z/p, n}^{unst} \tau_{\geq m} X = X$.
- The stable analog of Neisendorfer's theorem then says that if $L$ is a localization of $p$-complete spectra which kills $H\mathbb Z/p$, then for any spectrum $E$, $\tau_\geq n E \to E$ is an $L$-equivalence for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: What about MU-localization? Isn't this an example of a nontrivial localization which kills no $K(\mathbb{Z}/p,n)$?

Comment: @SaalHardali I thought MU-localization was the same as $H\mathbb Z$-localization, which is to say the identity...

Comment: Maybe I'm forgetting some hypotheses for this to be true...

Comment: $H\mathbb{Z}$-localization is not the identity. (For example it kills K-theory).

Comment: I would like to add that I gave $MU$ instead of the simpler $H\mathbb{Z}$ because its also not true that localization w.r.t. all the morava $K$-theories (i.e. the harmonic localization) is the same as $MU$-localization which indicates in some sense that there are baziilions of non-trivial loclization of this sort.

Comment: The link to Lee's theorem seems to be broken... is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Done. Annoyingly, jstor doesn't include a doi link on the webpage for a paper, so you have to construct the url by hand.

Comment: @TimCampion. Thanks! I actually just found it myself, but it might be helpful for others :)

Answer (score 3):

This question is more fun at the space level: see [Neisendorfer, Joseph A.
Localization and connected covers of finite complexes. The Čech centennial (Boston, MA, 1993), 385–390, Contemp. Math., 181, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1995.]

Comment: @NickolasKuhn: Your answer is somewhat cryptic. For the benefit of those who don't have the time to check the reference, a tiny bit of explanation of what happens at the space level would be very welcome.